# Prisma unique annotation

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

I'm with a problem where I can't create a 1:1 relationship in Prisma without the unique annotation.

Right now, my schema looks like this:

```
  model Transaction {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  type       Type?
  date       DateTime
  product    String
  value      Int
  seller     String
  typeTypeId Int      @unique
}


model Type {
  id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  description String
  nature      String
  sign        String
  transaction Transaction @relation(fields: [typeId], references: [typeTypeId])
  typeId      Int  @unique
}
```

The idea is that on the Type table, I'll have 4 fixed types (1, 2, 3, 4) and on the Transaction table I can have multiple records with the same type, but not two types on the same record, so:

On the Transaction table, a record with types 1, 2 would not be OK, but multiple records with the Type 1 is OK.

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my modeling or if there is something with Prisma that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your Prisma schema, you don't appear to be able to create a single `Transaction` which has multiple `Type`s. Do you mean multiple `Transaction`s can never have the same `Type`? Your `Transaction` model as written only associates itself with one `Type`, not multiple

Comment: Multiple transactions can have the same type, but just one type. I changed the transaction to `Transaction[]` and it worked. Thanks!